# How to set a navbar link "active" for multiple url with Django tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code

`navbar.html`:

```
{% url 'news:list' as news_url %}
{% url 'news:list-detail' as news_url_detail %}
[..]    
<ul class="navbar-nav">
 [..]        
 <li class="nav-item ">
   <a class="nav-link {% if request.path == news_url %}active{% endif %}" href="{{ news_url }}">News<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
   </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to set as active the navbar link "News" even if the current url is not the "News" one (`news_url`)

```
<a class="nav-link {% if request.path == news_url or request.path == news_url_detail %}active{% endif %}" href="{{ news_url }}">News<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
```

How can I do that?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

**EDIT 1**
/core/app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    [..]
    url(r'^newsandeventi/', include("newsandeventi.urls", namespace='newsandeventi')),
    [..]
]
```

/newsandeventi/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from newsandeventi.views import ArchiveView, CategoryListView, SearchView, EntryDetailView
# from blog.views import EntryDetailView, CategoryListView, ArchiveView, SearchView, SearchResultView # noqa


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ArchiveView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', EntryDetailView.as_view(), name='list-detail'),    
    url(r'^categoria/(?P<tag>[-\w .]+)/$', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-list'),
]
```

**EDIT 2:**
/newsandeventi/views.py

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entry
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.published()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['base_url'] = self.request.build_absolute_uri("/").rstrip("/")
        context['alltags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        context['fiveposts'] = Entry.objects.order_by('id')[:5]
        entries= Entry.objects.all()
        context['last_featured'] = entries.filter(featured=True).last()
        return context
```

The issue might rise from the class-based view `EntryDetailView`, when I call newsandeventi:list-detail, I'm not passing through the arguments    `year, month, day, slug`.

If this is the issue, How can I solve it?

Comment: Your example `{% if %}` conditional looks ok. Is this not working?

Comment: @WillKeeling: not working...

Comment: @WillKeeling: sorry to bother, what else could be wrong in my if statement?

Comment: The `url ... as` syntax will not cause an error if the view lookup fails. That might be happening which would then cause the `if` statement to not work as expected. Try temporarily removing `as news_url` and `as news_url_detail`. Does the page display a `NoReverseMatch` error?

Comment: Could you also post your `urls.py`?

Comment: @WillKeeling The error may rise in news_url_detail. In EDIT 2 I explained why, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are. The lookup will fail because the year/month/day/slug data is not being passed. A better solution might be to set a flag in the class based view itself. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
{% url 'news:list-detail' as news_url_detail %}
```

will silently fail because you're not passing the year/month/day/slug parameters required by the URL. The `{% url ... as var %}` syntax [does not cause an error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) if the view lookup fails.

A better approach to identify whether the rendered page is an `EntryDetailView` may be to set a flag in the context data, and then test for the existence of that flag.

For example:

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        context['is_entry'] = True  # Set a flag
        return context
```

And then in the template:

```
<a class="nav-link {% if request.path == news_url or is_entry %}active{% endif %}" href="{{ news_url }}">News<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
```